# Don't Show DateTime stamp in Commons Logging -- Maven

Tags: maven, logging

When I build and run a small program from the command line using Maven, I'd like to concisely see the output from my logging, but currently I'm seeing a timestamp and Java class location of the source of the log.  Can I hide that?

It must be a setting somewhere, but I'm not finding it.

The output looks like:

```
Mar 28, 2013 9:40:57 AM com.xxcompany.app.myClient getStarted
INFO: Startup, ..  My Info here
Mar 28, 2013 9:40:58 AM com.xxcompany.app.myClient getStarted
INFO: More Info here, but I don't want a timestamp
```

I don't want to see the log info:

```
Mar 28, 2013 9:40:57 AM com.xxcompany.app.myClient getStarted
```

The Java code:

```
import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;

....
logger.info("More Info here, but I don't want a timestamp");
```

In Maven POM:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.1</version>
</dependency>
```

And the call to Maven:

```
mvn compile exec:java -Dexec.mainClass="com.xxcompany.app.App"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's still an open issue for maven http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MNG-519
Couple of workarounds are provided there (a surgical one of customising a file in maven own jars and a homoeopathic one of piping though a script).